# enable keepalive on apache 301 redirect pages

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, connections, keepalive

I want to make it so that every website on the server I manage (including my own website) will enable keep-alive on all (HTTP status 301) redirect pages including ones issued by apache modules.

This means when I try to get the headers of the page, I should see `connection: keep-alive` in the header.

Is there a special setting in apache I could use for this? using mod_rewrite would cause me to rescript all my rules but it wouldn't help with apache's mod_dir because someone trying to access a folder without the correct number of slashes will be redirected and mod_rewrite can't control that.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to add header

```
Header set Connection keep-alive
```

> Context:  server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess

[Link to official doc : mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_headers.html)

Comment: Where are you suggesting this be added?

Comment: I updated the answer to add more information